# How to explicitly use an induction principle in coq?

Tags: coq, equality, agda, coq-tactic, homotopy-type-theory

I'm trying to prove symmetry of propositional identity with the induction principal explicitly in Coq, but can't do it with the induction principle like I can in agda. I don't know how to locally declare a variable in Coq, nor do I know how to unfold a definition, as you can see below.  How can I get a proof that resembles the agda one below?

```
Inductive Id (A : Type) (x : A) : A -> Type :=
  | refl : Id A x x.

(* trivial with induction *)
Theorem symId {A} {x y} : Id A x y -> Id A y x.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction H.
  apply refl.
Qed.

Check Id_ind.
(* Id_ind *)
(*      : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : forall a : A, Id A x a -> Prop), *)
(*        P x (refl A x) -> forall (y : A) (i : Id A x y), P y i *)

Theorem D {A} (x y : A) : Id A x y -> Prop.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply (Id A y x).
Qed.

Theorem d {A} (x : A) : D x x (refl A x).
Proof.
  apply refl.
Admitted.
```

This fails, how can I unfold D so that I can just assert reflexivity?

```
Theorem symId' {A} {x y} : Id A x y -> Id A y x.
Proof.
  intros.
```

how do I apply to the correct arguements? How can I locally assert D and d via tactics (is there a where or (let a = b in)  tactic ?)
  apply (Id_ind A x (forall a : A, Id A x a -> Prop)).

Here is the agda code I'm trying to emulate

```
data I (A : Set) (a : A) : A → Set where
r : I A a a

J2 : {A : Set} → (D : (x y : A) → (I A x y) →  Set)
  →  (d : (a : A) → (D a a r )) → (x y : A) → (p : I A x y) → D x y p
J2 D d x .x r = d x

refl-I : {A : Set} → (x : A) → I A x x
refl-I x = r

symm-I : {A : Set} → (x y : A) → I A x y → I A y x
symm-I {A} x y p = J2 D d x y p
  where
    D : (x y : A) → I A x y → Set
    D x y p = I A y x
    d : (a : A) → D a a r
    d a = r
```

Even though the coq and agda J's aren't equal, they are presumably interderivable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ending a proof with `Qed.` makes the proof opaque. Sometimes this is what you want, but if you ever want the computational content of a proof, you should end it with `Defined.` instead.

This should work since now `D` can be unfolded.

```
Inductive Id (A : Type) (x : A) : A -> Type :=
  | refl : Id A x x.

(* trivial with induction *)
Theorem symId {A} {x y} : Id A x y -> Id A y x.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction H.
  apply refl.
Qed.

Check Id_ind.
(* Id_ind *)
(*      : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : forall a : A, Id A x a -> Prop), *)
(*        P x (refl A x) -> forall (y : A) (i : Id A x y), P y i *)

Theorem D {A} (x y : A) : Id A x y -> Prop.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply (Id A y x).
Defined.

Theorem d {A} (x : A) : D x x (refl A x).
Proof.
  apply refl.
Qed.
```

---

As for your other questions. You can explicitly use induction in two ways. One is to use `Id_rect`, `Id_rec` or `Id_ind` (these are automatically declared when you define `Id`). For example,

```
Definition Id_sym {A: Type} {x y: A}: Id A x y -> Id A y x :=
Id_ind A x (fun y' _ => Id A y' x) (refl A x) y.
```

(using some implicit arguments might make this easier to read).

Ultimately, this gets converted into a match statement, so you could use that too.

```
Definition Id_sym' {A: Type} {x y: A} (p: Id A x y): Id A y x :=
  match p with
  | refl _ _ => refl _ _
  end.
```

---

To declare a local variable in a definition, you can use the `let var := term in term` form. For example, `Id_sym` above could be rewritten as

```
Definition Id_sym'' {A: Type} {x y: A}: Id A x y -> Id A y x :=
let P := (fun y' _ => Id A y' x) in
Id_ind A x P (refl A x) y.
```